# Problemas na Instalação do ESLINT

Tags: node.js

Estou com problemas na instalação do ESLINT (AIRBN) no VS Code, quando eu tento instalar, apresenta o erro abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei rodar `npm uninstall eslint` e `npm install eslint`, fechar o VS Code e abrir novamente, porém não funcionou e estou travado nisso, poderiam me ajudar, por favor?

Comment: Testa limpar a diretoria do `node_modules` e reinstalar... `rm -rf node_modules` e depois `npm install`.

Comment: fiz isso também, mas não funcionou :(

Comment: Já tentou fazer pelo power shell com permissão de administrador?

Comment: Sim , agora funcionou, obrigado!